# When do I unlock the review queue for low quality comments?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, comments, comment-flags

It's easy to avoid low quality questions by not browsing for questions. How about a queue for reviewing low quality comments instead? This community consistently makes me feel harassed online via comments, while questions and answers are downright legitimate and fair.

Comment: There is no such review queue. I think that harassing via comments is to be dealt by diamond mods, not by normal users.

Comment: There would need to be some amount of signal in order to determine which comments were potentially low quality. For example, if we could downvote comments, then that would be one possible benefit.

Comment: @TravisJ So that, for example, we could downvote repeated comments from the same user plugging their pet feature? ;-)

Comment: [List of privileges and the reputation needed to unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: I'd love it, but comments, though they contribute greatly to the culture of this site, are either considered unimportant, or belonging to the moderation of an elite few. Many questions about comments and improving any process around them are downvoted into oblivion. I think it is something we just have to accept.

Comment: @CodyGray - Exactly. So that you you could downvote a comment instead of leaving snarky passive aggressive comments all over the place. 

Answer (score 11):

There is no review queue for comments. At no [privilege level](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) are users asked or allowed to review comments.

Comments can, however, be [flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging), which brings them to the attention of diamond moderators:

[image: Red freehand circle: "Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention"]

Diamond moderators are presented with flagged comments in a queue of sorts, but it is a moderator-only tool. This is primarily because comment revision histories, editing tools, and other features are all moderator-only, so there is very little that a non-moderator user could do to investigate and/or resolve a problem.

It serves little to no purpose to have users going around *looking* for comments to flag. Reviewing all incoming comments would be a massive waste of time. If you come across them organically while browsing the site, then it's fine to flag them.

Comment: Also covered in the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) under Reporting...

Comment: Which links to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging), @Heretic. Do you think that should go into the answer?

Comment: I was thinking a reminder that harrassment is not tolerated might not be remiss. I hear a lot of complaints but not a lot of flagging.

Comment: Heh. I may have omitted that because of some insider knowledge that I may or may not have. Specifically, I may or may not have been the moderator who just declined one of the asker's flags on a comment here on Meta. Had I done that, it would have been because I *didn't* think it was harassment, or even unkind. But yeah, if you think the answer could use such a notice, feel free to edit. @Heretic